# WPF DataGrid data and columns not visible

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

What I have done is set up datagrid with multi row selection support. However the issue is that when `AutoGenerateColumns` is set to false the multi row selection works however the data that I upload from my data base does not show. When I switch `AutoGenerateColumns` to true, I can see the data but the single click multi select feature stops working.

Here is the xaml code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Hello" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Albums}"
              Grid.Row="0"
              AutoGenerateColumns="True"  SelectionMode="Extended" Loaded="dgCustomers_Loaded">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn ElementStyle="{DynamicResource MetroDataGridCheckBox}"
                                    EditingElementStyle="{DynamicResource MetroDataGridCheckBox}"
                                    Header="IsSelected"
                                    Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Path=IsSelected, Mode=OneWay}"
                                    />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

This is how I am filling in the datagrid:

```
private void dgCustomers_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        var grid = sender as DataGrid; //Creates its self as an object
        grid.ItemsSource = CustomerDataAdapter.GetData(); //Shows all of the data in the Customer table
    }
```

Comment: When you set AutoGenerate to False, the data does not show because you need to explicitly identify "what" data to show. You need to add your own columns, and bind them accordingly to the properties within the entity.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do both auto generate columns & specify columns explicitly in the XAML.  I believe it's one or the other.  I believe you have to set `AutoGenerateColumns` to false & specify each column & a binding for it.

Comment: That is a bit annoying. Thanks for the swift response.